# Stem with quanteda

Tags: r, quanteda

I use the following command to make stemming using quanteda

```
myDfm <- dfm(tokens_remove(tokens(df2, remove_punct = TRUE, stem = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE), stopwords(source = "smart")), 
                          ngrams = c(1,2))
```

However I receive this warning at the end:

```
Warning message:
Argument stem not used.
```

Is there any different option to implement stemming with `quanteda`?

Comment: Please be more pedagogical and include some context, e.g. explain what `quanteda` is, and share your data or a subset of it, i.e. of data frame `df2`.

Comment: It's just a warning.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you want `tokens_wordstem()`.  In your example, you are are supplying `stem = TRUE` to the `tokens()` argument, not to the `dfm()` call.  `tokens()` does not have `stem` as an argument (as the warning states).

For clarity I suggest using the pipe operator `%>%` to see the sequence of operations more clearly.

```r
library("quanteda")
## Package version: 1.4.0
## Parallel computing: 2 of 12 threads used.
## See https://quanteda.io for tutorials and examples.
## 
## Attaching package: 'quanteda'
## The following object is masked from 'package:utils':
## 
##     View

df2 <- data_char_sampletext
quanteda_options(verbose = TRUE)

df2 %>%
  tokens(remove_punct = TRUE, remove_numbers = TRUE, remove_symbols = TRUE) %>%
  tokens_remove(stopwords(source = "smart")) %>%
  tokens_wordstem() %>%
  tokens_ngrams(n = c(1, 2)) %>%
  dfm()
## removed 0 features
## 
## removed 72 features
## Creating a dfm from a tokens input...
##    ... lowercasing
##    ... found 1 document, 375 features
##    ... created a 1 x 375 sparse dfm
##    ... complete. 
## Elapsed time: 0.038 seconds.
## Document-feature matrix of: 1 document, 375 features (0.0% sparse).
```